# Using local configs in a Heroku deployment environment

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to migrate my app to Heroku - I have a config file that varies with development/staging/production environments as it contains uniquely assigned keys (from Facebook, S3, etc.), so I keep it out of the repository and keep the configs local.

As such I'm trying to find a solution for Heroku to have that config file since Heroku deploys from the repository. I noticed Heroku deploys from the master branch - can it deploy from another branch? Because then I could commit the Heroku configs there, and have it not overwrite the other environments' configs every time it pulls.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Heroku always launches the `master` branch of the Gt repo, but they support [config vars](http://docs.heroku.com/config-vars) to address exactly this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I also got a reply from a Heroku rep that "git push heroku <your branch>:master" can push another branch

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreman and heroku-config for this.

Check out the article at heroku dev center:

```
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars
```

I love this because you can keep the .env file in .gitignore and shield your production variables from ending up in the repository.